# Android untar a file permission denied

Tags: android, tar

I have a tar file that I want to download from an API and un-tar it, on most devices the code below works fine but on few devices it gives an error

code:

```
val untar = arrayOf("tar", "-xvf", file.absolutePath, "-C", tempDirectory.absolutePath)
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(untar)
```

Error on few devices only:

```
tar: exec gunzip: Permission denied
```

Comment: you are maybe dealing with tgz files, not tar? most likely issue with toybox applet, invoke gzip -d | tar manually

Comment: are you sure the path you are extracting on is available?
check also if the difference on this device is related to write on external storage or not...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right android permissions:

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, maybe tar which is a link to toybox is fine, but unzip which is a link to ziptool is not. Maybe you should try using apache commons compress, in order to bring your own dependecies and not rely on operation system issues, altough the solution is going to be more complex.